# Preselect items in a TreeView

Tags: javafx, treeview, tornadofx

I am implementing a category mapper. There are 2 TreeViews. Both contain categories from different sources. (Even they look like from the same source)

[image: Screenshot]

The user should be able to map ONE category from the left to multiple of the right treeview. This gets stored in a config file.

However, when the view is initially loaded and the user clicks on a category on the left, I want to preselect the mapped categories on the right, loaded from the config file.

I saw that I can do this with ONE selection, but I don't see an option to do this for multiple ones.

How can I achive this?

[Here a ootb running demo implementation](https://gist.github.com/andretietz/4b8308f2616e7419d3ca3871468fd651)

Comment: please see the api doc of Multiple/SelectionModel - f.i. `selectionModel.select` _adds_ the selected item, also there are other methods for multiple selection. When stuck, come back with a [mcve] that demonstrates what is not working as expected

Comment: see example on gist

Comment: nothing works unexpected, I have no idea how to achive this? That's why I am asking

Comment: repeating: read the api doc and look out for methods that add selections .. and/or read a basic tutorial on how to use fx controls (including their managing classes like SelectionModel. That's what we do when we are not yet good in new field, aren't we ;) And no links to external code please ..

Answer (score 0):

I went through your gist and it seemed that the problem was binding selections right? I did some light digging and found that binding observable lists isn't easy. I don't think I even saw a solution that wasn't just adding listeners to mock a binding. However, wrapping that list in a `SimpleListProperty` seemed to do the trick. Here's a demo:

```
class TestView : View() {
    // This mocks your target list in the ViewModel
    val targetList = SimpleListProperty(listOf<String>().asObservable())

    override val root = vbox(10) {
        // Both table views and tree views use an Observable Selection list
        listview(listOf("asefas", "asefasef", "asefasefasefase").asObservable()) {
            // Wrap in SimpleListProperty, then bind
            targetList.bind(SimpleListProperty(selectionModel.selectedItems))
            selectionModel.selectionMode = SelectionMode.MULTIPLE
        }

        setPrefSize(300.0, 300.0)
    }

    init {
        // Target list now reflects changes made to selection model
        targetList.addListener { _, _, change ->
            println("Selections changed to: $change")
        }
    }
}
```